# how to write labels along with data on top and bottom of each stack in bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to create a just like this one.[image: first_Image]

Now I am getting the value from data in my chart but I don't know how to add these labels like the names of companies above and below at each stack.

[image: my_chart]
I am attaching the js fiddle link in the comment.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ga8pz2f5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give both datasets a different align like this:

```
datasets: [
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data: company,
        backgroundColor: '#2FC798',
        borderColor: '#2FC798',
        borderWidth: 2.2,
        lineTension: 0.4,
        pointStyle: 'rectRot',
        datalabels: {
            align: 'start',
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data: sector,
        backgroundColor: '#C72151',
        borderColor: '#C72151',
        borderWidth: 2.2,
        lineTension: 0.4,
        pointStyle: 'rectRot',
        datalabels: {
            align: 'end',
        }
    },
],
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/wmkxecns/3/)

Comment: Thanks alot man. One more thing I want to write the name of companies along with the value now i dont understand where to input them into my chart.

Comment: @Adeel you would need to use [Object using custom properties](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object-using-custom-properties) with your chart. Then [format](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#data-transformation) it with both value and company name. Or use [Custom Labels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#custom-labels)

Comment: hey can you please help me with this company name, I have tried but i really dont know how to pass text as input data . tomorrow is my deadline of this.